# VS Code error: Cannot read property 'local' of undefined

Tags: visual-studio-code, linux-mint

Пытаюсь поставить плагин, где получаю ошибку:

> Cannot read property 'local' of undefined
>
> Failed to install '...'.

[image: VSCode error]

Похожий вопрос уже [был тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55296580/vscode-cannot-read-property-local-of-undefined/55303923#55303923?newreg=c2ec13bb131c41e0a9cc8d2634db53ad), однако ответ

*The following command from terminal will fix it:*

> sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.vscode

не помог, ошибка никуда не пропала. Другие операции с выдачей прав тоже ни к чему не привели.

Comment: Вы используете OS linux?

Comment: Да, linux mint.

Comment: попробуйте export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin

Comment: Увы, результата это не принесло.